# K-Nearest Neighbor Classifier Best K Value

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, scikit-learn, k-nn

I created a `KNeighborsClassifier` for my dataset adjusting the k hyper-parameter (the number of neighbors) in a for loop. The `k` value was between 1 and 20. The result was the graph below:

[image]

How do I interpret this graph? Which would be my best k value?

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways that you can choose your k value for kNN -

You can use the common formula k = sqrt(n) where n is the number of data points in your training set or you can try choosing k where there is a good balance between computation expense vs noise.

Consider your what fits your problem: 
Do you care about runtime? The higher the k, the more expensive computationally it is to run.

It looks like around  k= 6-10 you get some diminishing returns - you could set it there to get a good balance between noise and computation cost, but ultimately it is a very arbitrary selection, so pick what suits your use case best.

Comment: Isn't computation time mostly invariant of k? The distance metric still needs to be computed between all data points in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The picture is telling you that test accuracy is improving with higher k, while train accuracy is degrading marginally.  You can settle for k=15, because beyond that you have diminishing returns on the test accuracy.

In general, you want to select k that shoots for the highest test accuracy (unseen data).

Answer (score -2):

That is called an Elbow-Curve!  You need to look for the lowest train accuracy, or highest test accuracy, where the curve doesn't bend much more (y-axis), for a given increase in K (x-axis).  In your case, it's around 7, but you could make an argument for 10, I suppose.  As you increase your 'K' the accuracy improves, but only incrementally, and the cost (total compute resources, overall time to finish, etc.) will increase quite significantly.

Here is another example of a similar Elbow-Curve.

[image]

In this example, a good K would be around 7.

Here is some sample code for you to test, and further illustrate the point.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\your_path\\classified_data.csv",index_col=0)
df.head()

df.info()

df.describe()


l=list(df.columns)
l[0:len(l)-2]


from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()


scaler.fit(df.drop('TARGET CLASS',axis=1))
scaled_features = scaler.transform(df.drop('TARGET CLASS',axis=1))


df_feat = pd.DataFrame(scaled_features,columns=df.columns[:-1])
df_feat.head()


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X = df_feat
y = df['TARGET CLASS']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(scaled_features,df['TARGET CLASS'],
                                                    test_size=0.50, random_state=101)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
knn.fit(X_train,y_train)


KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
           metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=1, p=2,
           weights='uniform')


pred = knn.predict(X_test)


from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix
conf_mat=confusion_matrix(y_test,pred)
print(conf_mat)
```

Result:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.88      0.90      0.89       250
           1       0.90      0.87      0.89       250

    accuracy                           0.89       500
   macro avg       0.89      0.89      0.89       500
weighted avg       0.89      0.89      0.89       500
```

Continue:

```
print(classification_report(y_test,pred))


print("Misclassification error rate:",round(np.mean(pred!=y_test),3))

error_rate = []
# Will take some time
for i in range(1,60):

    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i)
    knn.fit(X_train,y_train)
    pred_i = knn.predict(X_test)
    error_rate.append(np.mean(pred_i != y_test))


plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.plot(range(1,60),error_rate,color='blue', linestyle='dashed', marker='o',
         markerfacecolor='red', markersize=8)
plt.title('Error Rate vs. K Value', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('K',fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Error (misclassification) Rate',fontsize=15)
```

[image]

```
# sample data avalable here:
# https://www.kaggle.com/shubh247/simple-way-handle-classified-data-using-knn/data
```

Comment: completely inaccurate answer, elbow rule is applied on k-means https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering) (unsupervised learning) the plot shown on the question is a validation curve https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/learning_curve.html .Besides this material seems to have been take from here https://medium.com/@moussadoumbia_90919/elbow-method-in-supervised-learning-optimal-k-value-99d425f229e7